# Using Poisson Kernel Identity

Tags: trigonometry

I have a problem where I need to use the Poisson Kernel identity:

$\frac{1-p^2}{1-2p\cos(\omega t)+p^2}=1+2\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty p^n\cos(n\omega t)$,  $~~~~~|p|<1$.

(1). When I have an expression $z(t)=\frac{1}{1+\alpha\cos(\omega t)}$, I can multiply and divide by $\beta>0$: $~~~z(t)=\frac{\beta}{\beta+\beta\alpha\cos(\omega t)}$ and then identify $\beta=1+p^2$ and $\alpha\beta=-2p$, from which $\beta$ can be found via a quadratic equation in $\beta$: $~~~\beta^2-\frac{4}{\alpha^2}\beta+\frac{4}{\alpha^2}=0$
leading to $\beta=\frac{2}{\alpha^2}(1-\sqrt{1-\alpha^2})$, which, using $p=-\alpha\beta/2$ ultimately leads us to the value of $p$:  $p=p(\alpha)=-1/\alpha(1-\sqrt{1-\alpha^2})$.

So we can write something like: $z(t)=\frac{\beta}{1-p^2}\left[1+2\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty p^n\cos(n\omega t) \right]$.

(2) Now there is a similar expression $z(t)=\frac{1}{(1+y(t))+(1+y(t))\alpha\cos(\omega t)}$. Can I choose, in a similar way, $1+y(t)=1+p^2$ and $\alpha(1+y(t))=-2p$. Can I find $p$ such that $p=p(y,\alpha)$ in a similar way?.